# Decimal number in go-memdb

Tags: database, go

I am trying to create a floating point column using go-memdb but seems like I am missing enough understanding + documentation to create one. Shouting out for help.
In the below example I need "price" to be a decimal number but in the current form is losing its precision. Not sure which indexer to implement.

```
type Product struct {
    ID          string  `json:"id"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Price       float32 `json:"price"`
    SKU         string  `json:"sku"`
    CreatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    DeletedOn   string  `json:"-"`
}

schema := &memdb.DBSchema{
        Tables: map[string]*memdb.TableSchema{
            "product": {
                Name: "product",
                Indexes: map[string]*memdb.IndexSchema{
                    "id": {
                        Name:         "id",
                        Unique:       true,
                        AllowMissing: false,
                        Indexer:      &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "ID"},
                    },
                    "name": {
                        Name:    "name",
                        Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "Name"},
                    },
                    "description": {
                        Name:    "description",
                        Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "Description"},
                    },
                    "price": {
                        Name:    "price",
                        Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "Price"},
                    },
                    "sku": {
                        Name:    "sku",
                        Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "SKU"},
                    },
                    "createdon": {
                        Name:    "createdon",
                        Indexer: &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "CreatedOn"},
                    },
                    "updatedon": {
                        Name:         "updatedon",
                        AllowMissing: true,
                        Indexer:      &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "UpdatedOn"},
                    },
                    "deletedon": {
                        Name:         "deletedon",
                        AllowMissing: true,
                        Indexer:      &memdb.StringFieldIndex{Field: "DeletedOn"},
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The go-memdb package currently doesn't have a dedicated floating point number index. It currently only for integer numbers. But the package exposes the `Indexer` interface, so that anyone can implement an index for a type. By checking the `IntFieldIndex`, you can have a good idea of the work needed to be done.